# second derivatives of a multivariate function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

A function f(x, y) is called Morse if all its critical points are nondegenerate.
A function f(x, y) is called harmonic if the equation $f_{xx}$ +$f_{yy}$= 0 holds for all x, y. Prove
that a harmonic Morse function does not have local maxima or minima, so its critical
points are always saddles.

What i know is that, for a function f(x,y) to have non degenerate critical points, its critical points must exists. Hence $f_{xx}$$f_{yy}$- ($f_{xy}$)^2 will not be zero.Im thinking of differentating the function o$f_{yy}$one  more time to get$f_{yyx}$ or $f_{xxy}$  Im stuck from here onwards. Could anyone help me with this. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f$ is harmonic, then $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0) = -f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)$ at any critical point $(x_0,y_0)$. You already mentioned that since critical points of $f$ are non-degenerate, the determinant of the Hessian of $f$ at $(x_0,y_0)$, is non-zero:
\begin{equation}
f_{xx}(x_0,y_0)f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)- (f_{xy}(x_0,y_0))^2 \neq 0.
\end{equation}
We want to show that $(x_0,y_0)$ is a saddle point.

What should the sign of $f_{xx}(x_0,y_0)f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)- (f_{xy}(x_0,y_0))^2$ be to ensure $(x_0,y_0)$ is a saddle point?

How might we use the fact that $f$ is harmonic to prove the desired conclusion?  (Hint: A substitution.)

Comment: Subsitute $-f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)$ into the equation to get -2($-f_{yy}(x_0,y_0)$)^2, hence expression will always be negative and is less than zero, hence a saddle point.Am i correct?